# C++ pointer problems

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

trying to create a diagonal-matrix with c++ but getting the following output: `

```
Enter Arraysize.5
5
Array sized [5,1987668707] created.

Array contents:
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0
0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0
0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0
0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1033072912 53910 7505208 74766
40
0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 1150447976 134271638 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1033072912 53910 7505208 7476640 35652354 50397954 34603592 3460353
6 34603536 34603536 34603536 34603794 36700688 34603536
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1033072912 53910 7505208 7476640 35652354 50397954 34603592 34603536 34603536 34603536 34603536 34603794
 36700688 34603536 34603536 34865684 51511824 34603536 34865680 34603794 34603536 34603536 50397953 50397953
```

`
The problem happens somewhere in the matrix_diagonal function...but I do not know exactly where. 
My curretnt code:

```
    #include <iostream>

int** matrix_diagonal(int size, int vals[]){
    int** array = 0;
    array = new int*[size];
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
        array[i] = new int[size];
        for(int k = 0; k<size;k++){
            array[i][k]= i == k ? vals[i] : 0;
        }
    }


    return array;
}



int main() {
    int size = 0;
    printf("Geben Sie eine matrixgröße an.");
    std::cin>>size;

    int sizeDia[]={1,3,4,6,2,5,8,3};
    int** matrixdia = matrix_diagonal(8,sizeDia);


    for (int h = 0; h < sizeof(sizeDia); h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < sizeof(sizeDia); w++)
        {
            printf("%i ", matrixdia[h][w]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int h = 0; h < sizeof(sizeDia); h++)
    {

        delete [] matrixdia[h];
    }

    matrixdia = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

I have no clue why this strange output is happening, but it looks like the values get correctly saved. Any ides how to fix this problem?

Comment: I think your array is initiating correctly, but the way you are printing the array is making problem. Try to debug the value of w in the print loops and see if that can flag anything.

Comment: `sizeof(sizeDia)` should be `sizeof(sizeDia) / sizeof(int)`

Comment: Why are you assigning `array` to 0 when you declare it?

Comment: `sizeof(sizeDia);` -- You could have [printed that value](https://ideone.com/qbChAX) to see what it really is.  Debugging your own code is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.

Comment: Thanks for your help...but why exactly is sizeof(sizeDia) / sizeof(int) working and sizeof(sizeDia) not? What exactly does sizeof(sizeDia) / sizeof(int) do? (In my opinion it divides sizeof(sizeDia) and sizeof(int))

Comment: @Finduson -- What does `sizeof(T)` return?  It returns **in bytes**, the size of the type, not the number of entries.  See the example I linked to.  So do the math on the division and you see why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links explain in details the sizeof operator on char and on int.

http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/

More especially, I would recommend you to read this part:

**The Basics**

> Firstly, the `sizeof()` operator **does not give you the
>   number of elements in an array**, it gives you the number of bytes a
>   thing occupies in memory. Hence:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>   char s[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0 };
>   int xs[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0 };
>
>   printf( "sizeof( s ) = %d\n",  sizeof( s  ) );
>   printf( "sizeof( xs ) = %d\n", sizeof( xs ) );
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> **Result:**
>
> ```
> sizeof( s ) = 6
> sizeof( xs ) = 24
> ```
>
> This causes some confusion, because the first time many beginners try
>   to use sizeof() is often with a character string, and a char is always
>   one byte long. An int, however, will be something different. (The
>   actual size depends on your computer. On mine, an int is four bytes
>   long, and six four-byte elements is 24 bytes total.)

Therefore, you should divide the size of your int array by the size of a int on your architecture to know the size of your array.

```
sizeof(sizeDia) / sizeof(int);
```